# How much faster is solving Clique in properly colored graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Given a graph $G$ and a proper vertex coloring $C$ with the minimum
numbers of colors, how much faster can a maximum clique be found than
when just $G$ is given?

Additional information doesn't make the problem harder, and it is
still NP-hard since [there are graph classes where coloring
is in P and clique is NP-hard](http://graphclasses.org/classes/AUTO_2153.html).

There might be some relation to hypergraphs.

We have the trivial bound $\omega(G) \le \chi(G)$, so an algorithm
which finds a clique of size $\chi(G)$ will stop.

Comment: What is the question here? if we can speed CLIQUE even though it remains NPC?

Comment: @RB I edited giving a bound which might help. Actually I am asking if we can speed clique with additional information which gives upper bound.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of those graph classes which clique is NP-hard but coloring is P?

Comment: @Saeed according to graphclases.org example is (3K_1,co-K_{1,5})-free -- check details for reference, link: http://graphclasses.org/classes/AUTO_2153.html

Comment: Doesn't the "it is still NP-hard" part of your posting answer your own question?

Comment: @DavidEppstein I think the upper bound makes it at least slightly easier/faster.